# Formula to get unique possible combinations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, numbers, vlookup

Is there any to get all possible outcome as below.

I have 2 word O & E

I want to get 6 character word with O & E like this

```
O O O O O O
E O O O O O
```

there are mane such possible results. If there any formula which will give possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy down this starting from row 1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(ROW()-1,6),"0","O"),"1","E")
```

Comment: Very neat approach!

Comment: Thank you very much for providing solutions. It's working very well. I have one more doubt in this. Now I want to modify this formula. For example I have 6 range (1-9), (11-19), (21-29), (31-39), (41-49) & (51-59) now I want to get possible combinations of these range with 6 Place. Like (1-9)(11-19)(21-29)(31-39)(41-49)(51-59) in possible manner. How can we do that.

Comment: @BrijeshTrivedi you cannot change your question **completely** (also see [ask]). The question that you originally asked is perfectly answered and what you ask now is something completely different. So you should mark this question as solved and ask a new question. • But make sure you incude your attempts and your research. This is no free code writinig service.